# How do I get the IP address of joined unit in install hook?

Tags: juju

I am new to Juju and charms, trying out basic things.

I am writing a charm(say client) which needs IP address of another charm(say server) in its install hook.

Basically, I need the IP address of server and put it in a configuration file of client. But it won't be available in the install hook of the client. I added relation of client and server and `$REMOTE-UNIT`and `relation-set hostname=unit-get private-address public-address=unit-get public-address` and `server_address=relation-get hostname` can be used.

However, this doesn't seem to work. The IP address of server must be made available to the client whilst in the `install hook`, right? Since it's a one time config parameter.

Comment: + what kind of server or do you simply mean a general host for any server ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, if I understand correctly, you want to install an application that needs a server ip in order to install correctly? What you basically have is **a client that is "useless" without a relationship to a server.**

Juju is event-based. When an event is triggered, Juju queues all other events for that charm. The next even gets fired from the moment the previous one is done. The `relation` events will only get fired after the `install` event is completed. Technically speaking, the relation between two charms can only be added after the `install` hook of a charm finishes.

If you have a charm that cannot install unless it has a relation (unless it knows the "server" ip) then the `install` hook does nothing. **The actual installation should happen in the `relation-joined` hook.**

So implement this:

- `install` hook basically does nothing [1]
- `relation-joined` hook gets the ip using `relation-get private-address`
- `relation-joined` hook does the actual installation and configuration of the client

[1] *or the install hook can do the installation up to the point that the ip is needed, and then stop*

Comment: Thank you Galgalesh, this is precisely what I needed :-)